# Getting infinite type error when making function that runs its input on itself

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeerror

I'm trying to figure out why this code is not working as intended.

I want to make a function `run` that takes as input some function and returns that function applied to itself.

```
run::(t1->t2)->t2
run a = a a
```

The types included are supposed to be general because I want this to work on anything, but I'm getting and infinite type error when I try and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Wasn't the point of creating a type system for lambda calculus to make ω, and thus Ω, inexpressible?

Comment: Can you show a function that you want to pass to `run`? What should the result be?

Answer (score 5):

You say `a :: t1 -> t2`. This means its argument should have type `t1`. Then you apply it to itself, `a a`. This means its argument is `a`.

So now we have an equation: the argument should have both the type `t1` (because it is an argument to `a`) and the type `t1 -> t2` (because it is `a`):

```
t1 ~ t1 -> t2
   ~ (t1 -> t2) -> t2
   ~ ((t1 -> t2) -> t2) -> t2
   ~ (((t1 -> t2) -> t2) -> t2) -> t2
   ~ ...
```

Each line follows from the previous by replacing `t1` by the thing it's equal to, `t1 -> t2`. No finite types satisfy the given equality.

Answer (score 4):

You write

```
run::(t1->t2)->t2
run a = a a
```

Because `a` is the argument of the function,

```
a :: t1 -> t2
```

Now you're applying `a` to `a`. The argument of `a` has type `t1`, so we must have

```
a :: t1
```

The only this can make sense is if `t1` is the same as `t1 -> t2`. So that would mean

```
t1
= t1 -> t2
= (t1 -> t2) -> t2
= ((t1 -> t2) -> t2) -> t2
= ...
```

That's probably where your infinite type error comes from. I'm not sure why you don't get a simpler error saying that `t1` is not the same as `t1 -> t2`.

So ... you can't *exactly* call a function with itself in Haskell. You *can* do some similar things, with some care. But how you do it will depend on exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you don't get a simpler error saying that t1 is not the same as `t1 -> t2`" Isn't that just because the two types *are* the same, if we allow that `t2 ~ (t1 -> t2)`?

Comment: @amalloy, we *can't* allow that, because both types are parameters. If I write `foo :: a -> b; foo = id`, that will not typecheck, because we can't just allow `a ~ b`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write the equivalent of (λx. xx) (λx. xx) or a Y combinator in Haskell, it can be done:

```
Prelude> newtype F t2 = Wrap {unwrap :: F t2 -> t2}
Prelude> run x = (unwrap x) x
Prelude> :t run
run :: F t2 -> t2
Prelude> run (Wrap run)
^C
Interrupted.
Prelude> myFix f = run (Wrap (\x -> f ((unwrap x) x)))
Prelude> factorial = myFix (\fac n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * fac (n - 1))
Prelude> factorial 5
120
```

Adding and removing the newtype wrapper is a no-op at runtime.

Haskell doesn't allow this sort of self-referential ("infinite") type without a `data` or `newtype` wrapper. Automatically inferring infinite types is possible, and wouldn't make the type system any more inconsistent than it already is, but infinite types aren't very useful, and they often show up by accident in buggy code that really shouldn't type check, so it's probably better that they're rejected.